# UML - How would you draw a try catch in a sequence diagram?

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

Is there a standard way of drawing try catch sequence diagrams? I've made an attempt based on [this](http://mscerts.programming4.us/image/201108/Unhandled%20Exceptions%20in%20Tasks_1.jpg) but I feel like the end result doesn't feel right.

Code the diagram is based around:

```
public static void save () {
        try {
            FileHandle filehandle = Gdx.files.external(file);

            filehandle.writeString(Boolean.toString(ConstantsHandler.soundEnabled)+"\n", false);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                filehandle.writeString(Integer.toString(ConstantsHandler.highscores[i])+"\n", true);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
    }
```

My Attempt
[image]

Note: I know I still need to add a for loop.

Comment: could you provide the uml code of the above diagram ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's perfectly ok. Fragments are meant to show conditional control flow in a sequence diagram. Superstructures puts some limitations on the use of fragments (see pp. 467 of SS2.1.1). So you should use a `Critical Region` for the `Try` part above. And `Option` for the `Catch`.

However, I keep telling that you can take quite some freedom in using UML. It's a language and as such it changes in life time. As long as your reader gets the idea you want to express, everything is perfect.

Comment: The purpose is to indicate the fragment and label it properly rather than a concrete set of rules regarding the actual state e.g. try catch? so fragments essentially create all iterations in sequence diagrams if they're labeled and used in the correct fashion?

Comment: Agree with @Thomas Kilian, even standards should be seen as guidelines, not all cases can be strictly supported. And, `Alt-Else` fragments are the most similar equivalent to the `Try-Catch` sentence.